# Best way to implement a own datamodel in magento or is it needed?

Tags: extension-attributes

i have a magento 2.4 shop where i should import many attibutes, so for each product i need to know in which car the part is usable. The car has 4 important values i need to know. Those are make, model, year of construction, cubic. I need those values, because i need to search for it later and the customer should be able to choose his car and get all parts for this car back.

My first attempt was to add EAV attributes as strings like this: "BMW/X5/2006/2000cc". Here i end up with 24k combinations, which slows the admin page (store->attribute products->make_model_year_cc attribute) very much.

Furthermore i have to save some more information for certain product/car combinations. For instance there are products which are needed more often than others in certain cars, i want to display this information to the customer, if he has choosen a certain car as his model.

I looked into magentos extension attributes as well, but im not sure if this would be the right way to go

My goal is to save the need information as described into magento, with the following requirements:

```
the ui should be usable, i will not getting around writing a magento plugin for data maintenance.

the data should be indexed by elasticsearch (this is why i wanted to stick to EAV attributes, they are indexed automatically)
```

Thanks so far..

Comment: I don't exactly see what speaks against using 4 (multi-)select attributes at this point. Surely the model attribute could get a bit messy unless you set up a custom dataprovider allowing to filter options based on selected make (or simply set the models option's admin value to contain the make as well) but this should still end up with far less than 24k options. Custom in FE then could filter by make and get relevant further attribute's options.

Comment: One product can match many cars. a car is clearly identified through (make, model, year, model). i cannot see how i can save thouse values in multiple attributes. So a car can match for example: BMW/1er;2000cc;2020 and VW;Passat;1900cc;2019. if im saving those values in multi select values im loosing the connection between the cars. I could not say if the part would match BMW;190cc;2019 for example, which in my example isnt a valid car.

Comment: Combined with a configurable product this should be possible, or does it have to be a single simple one only?

Comment: i thought about this too, but its really the same product there are no differences, everything is the same, even stock.